# AngularJS gets JSON file but it won't display

Tags: json, angularjs

I am working in a small AngularJS(1.6.6) website right now, I am calling a (local)JSON file from my projects.js component (not my main/index js file).
The data is retrieved and in the console, the JSON array gets displayed when I  console.log($scope.projectItems). However, when I try to pull that data and displayed that to the end-user using ng-repeat, nothing is being displayed and also there are no errors in the console.

Can anyone give me a suggestion of what I can be doing wrong?
Thank you.

```
[{
        "Name": "Home 1",
        "Text": "This is the Image of home 1"
    },
    {
        "Name": "Home 2",
        "Text": "This is the Image of home 2"
    }
]
```

```
<ul class="Projects_List">
    <li class="Project_Item" ng-repeat="Item in $ctrl.projectItems"> 
        {{Item.Name}}
      </li>
</ul>
```

```
angular.
module('App').
component('projects', {
    templateUrl: "projects.html",
    controller: function ProjectController($scope, $http) {

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'HomeProjects.json'
        }).then(function(data) {
            $scope.projectItems = data;
            console.log($scope.projectItems);
            console.log("This is working");

        }, function(error) {
            console.log("There is an error");
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Component controllers should avoid the use of $scope. It makes the migration to Angular 2+ more difficult.

Instead use the `this` context:

```
app.component('projects', {
    templateUrl: "projects.html",
    controller: function ProjectController( ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶ , $http) {
        var $ctrl = this;
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'HomeProjects.json'
        ̶}̶)̶.̶t̶h̶e̶n̶(̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶d̶a̶t̶a̶)̶ ̶{̶
        }).then(function(response) {
            ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶p̶r̶o̶j̶e̶c̶t̶I̶t̶e̶m̶s̶ ̶=̶ ̶d̶a̶t̶a̶;̶
            $ctrl.projectItems = response.data;
            console.log($ctrl.projectItems);
            console.log("This is working");

        }, function(error) {
            console.log("There is an error");
            throw error;
        });

    }
});
```

Also the $http service promise returns a `response` object of which `data` is a property.

Comment: Thank you, this is working now. However, I don't understand why you are storing this in the $ctrl, if $ctrl is the controller? 
could you please explain that? 
what I did instead was to store this in a different variable call vm and still works.

Thank you.

Comment: In the controller, one can assign `this` to any identifier. I used `$ctrl` because it matches how the controller is bound to scope. Some people use `vm`. Any identifier will work.

Answer (score 0):

In the template you are trying to access the items on the controller but they are on the scope.

Try change this

```
<li class="Project_Item" ng-repeat="Item in $ctrl.projectItems">
```

To this

```
<li class="Project_Item" ng-repeat="Item in projectItems">
```

Comment: Component controllers should avoid the use of `$scope`. It makes the migration to Angular 2+ more difficult.